# Mvc 4 - How to pass parameters to a partial view with viewbag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, viewbag, viewdata

I have a _Layout page and in this _Layout page, I am calling a Partial View as below.

```
<div>
    @{Html.RenderAction("_Account", "Home");}
</div>
```

_Account.cshtml

...

```
    @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                <p class="navbar-text navbar-right"> ****I want to write here "UserName"****</p>           }
```

As you see, I want to write userName if the user is authenticated. ( this is my question :) )

As you can expect, I have an Login controller..

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(UserModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        // My codes for login ...
        var response = _userService.UserGet(request.UserName,request.Password);

        if(response != null)
         {
            ViewBag.UserName = response.User.Name;
         }
      // My another codes....
    }
```

So, here is my question. I want to use this "ViewBag.UserName" in _Account partial view. I don t wanna use cookies.  Is there any way to to id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

Main View:

```
@Html.RenderAction("AccountPartial", "Home")
```

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AccountPartial(UserModel model, string returnUrl)
{
// My codes for login ...
        var response = _userService.UserGet(request.UserName,request.Password);

        if(response != null)
         {
            ViewBag.UserName = response.User.Name;
         }
      // My another codes....
 return PartialView("~/Views/Home/_Account.cshtml",model);
}
```

Partial View:

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
 <p class="navbar-text navbar-right">@ViewBag.UserName</p>           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Satpal said

```
 @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    <p class="navbar-text navbar-right">@ViewBag.UserName</p>           
    }
```

Isn't it simple???

Comment: hi Satpal. No it is not working. I am creating this ViewBag in Login controller which has no relation with _layout page or _Account partial view. I must do something to pass this parameter to this partial view..

Comment: See following link and you will understand everything http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/various-ways-to-pass-data-from-controller-to-view-in-mvc/

Answer (score 0):

just use @User.Identity.Name to get the username